# kuberntes oauth2-proxy with github provider return 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: kubernetes, github, ingress, oauth

I'am trying to add an authentication from Kubernetes ingerss with oauth2-proxy github provider

i have set everything according to the official documentaion

the url works and it redirects me to use my github account
[image]

but after login in it redircts me to a page with 500 Internal Server Error :

[image]

here is how i setup my github app :

[image]

my ingress for kubernetesUI and oauth proxy :

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-protocol: "HTTPS"
    cert-manager.io/cluster-issuer: "letsencrypt-prod"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-response-headers: Authorization
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-url: "https://$host/oauth2/auth"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-signin: "https://$host/oauth2/start?rd=$escaped_request_uri"
  name: ingress
  namespace: kubernetes-dashboard
spec:
  rules:
  - host: kubernetesui.***.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          service:
            name: kubernetes-dashboard
            port:
              number: 443
        path: /
        pathType: Prefix
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - kubernetesui.***.com
    secretName: kubeui
---
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: oauth2-proxy
  namespace: kubernetes-dashboard
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  rules:
  - host: kubernetesui.***.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /oauth2
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: oauth2-proxy
            port:
              number: 4180
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - kubernetesui.***.com
    secretName: kubeui
```

my proxy options :

```
  spec:
      containers:
      - args:
        - --provider=github
        - --email-domain=*
        - --upstream=file:///dev/null
        - --http-address=0.0.0.0:4180
        # Register a new application
        # https://github.com/settings/applications/new
        env:
        - name: OAUTH2_PROXY_CLIENT_ID
          value: ******
        - name: OAUTH2_PROXY_CLIENT_SECRET
          value: ***********
        # docker run -ti --rm python:3-alpine python -c 'import secrets,base64; print(base64.b64encode(base64.b64encode(secrets.token_bytes(16))));'
        - name: OAUTH2_PROXY_COOKIE_SECRET
          value: *************
```

proxy logs :

```
192.168.189.44:58052 - ********* - - [2022/09/14 13:43:24] kubernetesui.*****.com GET - "/oauth2/auth" HTTP/1.1 "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/105.0.0.0 Safari/537.36" 401 13 0.000
192.168.189.44:58056 - *********- - [2022/09/14 13:43:24] kubernetesui.****.com GET - "/oauth2/start?rd=%2F" HTTP/1.1 "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/105.0.0.0 Safari/537.36" 302 310 0.000
[2022/09/14 13:43:25] [oauthproxy.go:775] Error creating session during OAuth2 callback: unexpected status "404": {"message":"Not Found","documentation_url":"https://docs.github.com/rest/reference/users#list-email-addresses-for-the-authenticated-user"}
192.168.189.44:58056 - *******- - [2022/09/14 13:43:24] kubernetesui.*******.com GET - "/oauth2/callback?code=947a40cc3606f6f15821&state=7ocJxLTnigFxcUCiS_3hJ28Kr6MYyCxrZTYA1La52JA%3A%2F" HTTP/1.1 "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/105.0.0.0 Safari/537.36" 500 2837 0.453
```

hope someone can guide me to the right direction

Comment: It seems to be [a known issue](https://github.com/oauth2-proxy/oauth2-proxy/issues/1724) in the recent releases, with [a proposed workaround](https://github.com/oauth2-proxy/oauth2-proxy/issues/1669#issuecomment-1168287830). Since you didn't provide the version you're using, unknown if it applies to you, but worth trying

Comment: im using the latest version, i added the --scope but the same error produces

Comment: If you dig a bit deeper through the comments, it seems that adding --scope (via command-line argument) does not really work. You need to add it via config file (or - untested! - via environment variable). See [here](https://github.com/oauth2-proxy/oauth2-proxy/issues/1724#issuecomment-1452498288)